# I am having difficulty trying to strap a background url image solely to my home.html.erb on my RAILS 4.2.4 project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, background

I am having difficulty trying to strap a background url image solely to my home.html.erb on my RAILS 4.2.4 project.

Should this be imported in?

A) bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss

B) pages.scss

C) application.css

THIS IS MY CODE BELOW.

```
body {
background: url('../images/japan.png');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is load a specific stylesheet for the homepage

There are many ways to do this, i would go for a block like this inside the `<head>` of the application.html.erb

```
<%= yield :head %>
```

And inside your home.html.erb at the top preferably place a block like this:

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "home" %>
<% end %>
```

This will insert the contents of the block at the spot where you inserted `yield :head`

This way the stylesheet is only included on the homepage.

Now for the image, in the home.css.scss add your css for the body being:

```
body {
  background: image-url('japan.png');
}
```

The image-url method is a helper method which works hand in hand with the asset pipeline. In development it will insert the path with `app/assets/images/japan.png` and when in production with compiled assets it will insert the compiled asset path for the japan.png image

Comment: where is the syntax to call the image please and where does it go. right now nothing is loading

Comment: Please make a file in app/assets/stylesheets called home.css.scss and place the css for the background image in there

Comment: the image is called japan.png where does this code go.im getting confused with your note

Comment: The code goes inside `app/assets/stylesheets/home.css.scss`

Comment: Fabian, I don't think you understand my question mate. I have created that folder as you stipulated, my Japan.png is in the assets/images folder. I want that japan image strapped handsomely over the home.html.erb. where in your code do I apply or refer to the file path of japan.png

Comment: Okay cool we tackled singling out the homepage for the japan.png bg image, now for the image please see the edit to my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101221/discussion-between-fabian-de-pabian-and-chris-dormani).

Comment: This works to an extent but the background image is on every page now. How can I get it solely on the home.html.erb . I followed your code exactly!!

Comment: Remove `require_tree .` from application.css

Comment: *= require_self
 *= require 'masonry/transitions'
 *= require_tree .
 */
I have masonry/transitions as a core part of my index page. Will removing the require_tree F*&% this up

Comment: `require_tree` includes all files that are not included yet. But you have a page specific stylesheet so you dont want all files included at all times. Therefore from now on every stylesheet needs to be added by hand to the application.css file

Comment: thanks for your help and courtesy. I have marked the answer up.